# How to use Python decorators to check function arguments?

Tags: python, python-decorators

I would like to define some generic decorators to check arguments before calling some functions.

Something like:

```
@checkArguments(types = ['int', 'float'])
def myFunction(thisVarIsAnInt, thisVarIsAFloat)
    ''' Here my code '''
    pass
```

Side notes:

1. Type checking is just here to show an example
2. I'm using Python 2.7 but Python 3.0 whould be interesting too

EDIT 2021: funny that type checking did not go antipythonic in the long run with [type hinting](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html) and [mypy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Comment: As a note, this is generally a really bad idea - it goes against the grain of Python. Type checking is a bad thing in almost all cases. It's also worth noting that it might make more sense to use argument annotations to do this if you are in 3.x.

Comment: @Lattyware: Enforcing function arguments and return types is one of examples in [the original pep for decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Type checking was given has an example.

Comment: @Robᵩ I've updated my title to make it clearer.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian It's given as an example, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea 99.9% of the time.

Comment: @AsTeR - The code in your post answers the question in your title. Do you have some other, more specific question?

Comment: @Lattyware: it's unpythonic, but if you really want to do it, decorator and argument annotation is the best way to do it.

Comment: You guys are trolling right ? or Is it me becoming quite touchy on this philosophical point ? ;)

Comment: I'm not trolling, I'm just making the point that most of the time, if you are type checking, you are doing it wrong, and would be better off doing it another way. It's really common to see people on SO type checking and producing inflexible functions that don't work as well or as efficiently thanks to type checking.

Comment: here's a [very verbose answer on how to make decorators](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/4279)

Comment: Thanks I read it before, I didn't find my answer. After double check... It's there. I guess it's rather complete, but not that much specific !

Comment: Is there anyway I can see why I've so much "close" votes ?

Comment: @AsTeR: [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1594484/4279) is meant to improve the understanding of decorators. Read it from top to bottom, copy and run every code example from it. Make sure you understand `decorator_maker_with_arguments()` example.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [Decorators for Functions and Methods](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/):

**Python 2**

```
def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(types) == f.func_code.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
                assert isinstance(a, t), \
                       "arg %r does not match %s" % (a,t)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.func_name = f.func_name
        return new_f
    return check_accepts
```

**Python 3**

In Python 3 `func_code` has changed to `__code__` and `func_name` has changed to `__name__`.

```
def accepts(*types):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(types) == f.__code__.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
                assert isinstance(a, t), \
                       "arg %r does not match %s" % (a,t)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.__name__ = f.__name__
        return new_f
    return check_accepts
```

Usage:

```
@accepts(int, (int,float))
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2

func(3, 2) # -> 6
func('3', 2) # -> AssertionError: arg '3' does not match <type 'int'>
```

*`arg2` can be either `int` or `float`*

Comment: I'm using it on some method, but it seems that f has always the value of the last defined function. Do you happen to know where this could come from ?

Comment: @AsTeR: Create a [minimal complete code](http://sscce.org/) example that reproduces your problem and [post it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Comment: I will, my demand was just in case something obvious poped in your mind.

Comment: I recommend to use this solution, it has good readability if there are many input params. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578809-decorator-to-check-method-param-types/

Comment: getting an error on `f.func_code`: `function` object has no attribute 'func_code'

Comment: @IAbstract : the example is verbatim from the pep that uses Python 2.4 code (click the link). Specific details are unrelated to the question ("how to use decorators.."). What the current code should use depends on your case—I would start with `typing` module (that you could use with `mypy` static checker) and see whether it works in your case.

Comment: @IAbstract In Python 3, `func_code` (as I know) has been replaced with the magic attribute `__code__` instead.

Comment: @user4447514  func_name has also been replaced by `__name__`

Comment: Doesn't this solution break if I call `func(3, arg2=2)`? Then, `3` is in `*args` and `2` is in `**kwargs` because the latter was provided as keyword argument.

Comment: @daniel.neumann: the answer was just an example (to answer how it can be done). See also [my earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299878/how-to-use-python-decorators-to-check-function-arguments/15300191?noredirect=1#comment58446268_15300191)

Answer (score 19):

On Python 3.3, you can use function annotations and inspect:

```
import inspect

def validate(f):
    def wrapper(*args):
        fname = f.__name__
        fsig = inspect.signature(f)
        vars = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(*pair) for pair in zip(fsig.parameters, args))
        params={k:v for k,v in zip(fsig.parameters, args)}
        print('wrapped call to {}({})'.format(fname, params))
        for k, v in fsig.parameters.items():
            p=params[k]
            msg='call to {}({}): {} failed {})'.format(fname, vars, k, v.annotation.__name__)
            assert v.annotation(params[k]), msg
        ret = f(*args)
        print('  returning {} with annotation: "{}"'.format(ret, fsig.return_annotation))
        return ret
    return wrapper

@validate
def xXy(x: lambda _x: 10<_x<100, y: lambda _y: isinstance(_y,float)) -> ('x times y','in X and Y units'):
    return x*y

xy = xXy(10,3)
print(xy)
```

If there is a validation error, prints:

```
AssertionError: call to xXy(x=12, y=3): y failed <lambda>)
```

If there is not a validation error, prints:

```
wrapped call to xXy({'y': 3.0, 'x': 12})
  returning 36.0 with annotation: "('x times y', 'in X and Y units')"
```

You can use a function rather than a lambda to get a name in the assertion failure.

Comment: Looks interesting but really tough to understand at first glance. I'll give a look when I'll be less tired.

Comment: This is an _incredibly_ obfuscatory implementation. Technically, it works. But it makes the eyes bleed. For a far more readable (albeit slightly less powerful) alternative, see [sweeneyrod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2387370/sweeneyrod)'s concise [`@checkargs` decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684962/2809027) under a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19684962/2809027).

Comment: @CecilCurry: Can you elaborate why you think it is so bad? I think the checking via lambda very sensible.

Answer (score 12):

As you certainly know, it's not pythonic to reject an argument only based on its type.
Pythonic approach is rather "try to deal with it first"
That's why I would rather do a decorator to convert the arguments

```
def enforce(*types):
    def decorator(f):
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            #we need to convert args into something mutable   
            newargs = []        
            for (a, t) in zip(args, types):
               newargs.append( t(a)) #feel free to have more elaborated convertion
            return f(*newargs, **kwds)
        return new_f
    return decorator
```

This way, your function is fed with the type you expect
But if the parameter can quack like a float, it is accepted

```
@enforce(int, float)
def func(arg1, arg2):
    return arg1 * arg2

print (func(3, 2)) # -> 6.0
print (func('3', 2)) # -> 6.0
print (func('three', 2)) # -> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'three'
```

I use this trick (with proper conversion method) to deal with [vectors](http://holy-python.com/wordpress/la-librairie-vector2d-classe-vector2/).
Many methods I write expect MyVector class as it has plenty of functionalities; but sometime you just want to write

```
transpose ((2,4))
```

Comment: "As you certainly know, it's not pythonic to reject an argument only based on its type.". Do you have reference for that?

Comment: I believe he's referencing "duck typing", if it quacks like a duck and walks like a duck then it's a duck... but then I would argue with primitive types, such as float and decimal, eg. `Decimal(1.3)` is not the same as `Decimal('1.3')`

Comment: Doesn't this solution break if I call `func(3, arg2=2)`? Then, `3` is in `*args` and `2` is in `**kwargs` because the latter was provided as keyword argument.

Answer (score 8):

The package [`typeguard`](https://pypi.org/project/typeguard/) provides a decorator for this, it reads the type information from type annotations, it requires Python >=3.5.2 though. I think the resulting code is quite nice.

```py
@typeguard.typechecked
def my_function(this_var_is_an_int: int, this_var_is_a_float: float)
    ''' Here my code '''
    pass
```

Answer (score 2):

To enforce string arguments to a parser that would throw cryptic errors when provided with non-string input, I wrote the following, which tries to avoid allocation and function calls:

```
from functools import wraps

def argtype(**decls):
    """Decorator to check argument types.

    Usage:

    @argtype(name=str, text=str)
    def parse_rule(name, text): ...
    """

    def decorator(func):
        code = func.func_code
        fname = func.func_name
        names = code.co_varnames[:code.co_argcount]

        @wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args,**kwargs):
            for argname, argtype in decls.iteritems():
                try:
                    argval = args[names.index(argname)]
                except ValueError:
                    argval = kwargs.get(argname)
                if argval is None:
                    raise TypeError("%s(...): arg '%s' is null"
                                    % (fname, argname))
                if not isinstance(argval, argtype):
                    raise TypeError("%s(...): arg '%s': type is %s, must be %s"
                                    % (fname, argname, type(argval), argtype))
            return func(*args,**kwargs)
        return decorated

    return decorator
```

Comment: I ended up using this one: relatively simple, uses only standard library, and it works with variable number of *args and **kwargs. Only caveat is that `func_code` was renamed to `__code__` in Python 3, I don't know if there's a cross-version way to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the Python 3.5 answer to this question is [beartype](https://gist.github.com/leycec/3d48cc60e7d5fe8860b077acb067dc54). As explained in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39145690/4680402) it comes with handy features. Your code would then look like this

```
from beartype import beartype
@beartype
def sprint(s: str) -> None:
   print(s)
```

and results in

```
>>> sprint("s")
s
>>> sprint(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 13, in func_beartyped
TypeError: sprint() parameter s=3 not of <class 'str'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly improved version of @jbouwmans sollution, using python decorator module, which makes the decorator fully transparent and keeps not only signature but also docstrings in place and might be the most elegant way of using decorators

```
from decorator import decorator

def check_args(**decls):
    """Decorator to check argument types.

    Usage:

    @check_args(name=str, text=str)
    def parse_rule(name, text): ...
    """
    @decorator
    def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
        code = func.func_code
        fname = func.func_name
        names = code.co_varnames[:code.co_argcount]
        for argname, argtype in decls.iteritems():
            try:
                argval = args[names.index(argname)]
            except IndexError:
                argval = kwargs.get(argname)
            if argval is None:
                raise TypeError("%s(...): arg '%s' is null"
                            % (fname, argname))
            if not isinstance(argval, argtype):
                raise TypeError("%s(...): arg '%s': type is %s, must be %s"
                            % (fname, argname, type(argval), argtype))
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
return wrapper
```

Answer (score 1):

All of these posts seem out of date - pint now provides this functionality built in. See [here](http://pint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrapping.html#checking-dimensionality). Copied here for posterity:

> Checking dimensionality When you want pint quantities to be used as
>   inputs to your functions, pint provides a wrapper to ensure units are
>   of correct type - or more precisely, they match the expected
>   dimensionality of the physical quantity.
>
> Similar to wraps(), you can pass None to skip checking of some
>   parameters, but the return parameter type is not checked.
>
> ```
> >>> mypp = ureg.check('[length]')(pendulum_period)
> ```
>
> In the decorator format:
>
> ```
> >>> @ureg.check('[length]')
> ... def pendulum_period(length):
> ...     return 2*math.pi*math.sqrt(length/G)
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you could try with the [pydantic validation_decorator](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/validation_decorator/). from the documentation **pydantic**:

> Data validation and settings management using python type annotations.
> pydantic enforces type hints at runtime, and provides user friendly
> errors when data is invalid.
> In [benchmarks](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/benchmarks/) pydantic is faster than all other tested libraries.

```
from pydantic import validate_arguments, ValidationError


@validate_arguments
def repeat(s: str, count: int, *, separator: bytes = b'') -> bytes:
    b = s.encode()
    return separator.join(b for _ in range(count))


a = repeat('hello', 3)
print(a)
#> b'hellohellohello'

b = repeat('x', '4', separator=' ')
print(b)
#> b'x x x x'

try:
    c = repeat('hello', 'wrong')
except ValidationError as exc:
    print(exc)
    """
    1 validation error for Repeat
    count
      value is not a valid integer (type=type_error.integer)
    """
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the codes shared above looks complicated. What I did for defining 'generic decorator' for type-check:

I used *args, **kwargs feature, little extra work when using function/method but easy to manage.

***Appropriate example definition for test***

```
argument_types = {
'name':str,
'count':int,
'value':float
}
```

***Decoration Defination***

```
//from functools import wraps

def azure_type(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def type_decorator(*args, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if key in argument_types:
                if type(value) != argument_types[key]:
                    #enter code here
                    return 'Error Message or what ever you like to do'  
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return type_decorator
```

***Simple sample in code***

```
// all other definitions

@azure_type
def stt(name:str, value:float)->(int):
    #some calculation and creation of int output 
    count_output = #something int
    return count_output

// call the function:

stt(name='ati', value=32.90) #can test from that
```