# Type-checking Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, typechecking

I want to type-check Pandas DataFrames i.e. I want to specify which column labels a DataFrame must have and what kind of data type (`dtype`) is stored in them. A crude implementation (inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299878/how-to-use-python-decorators-to-check-function-arguments)) would work like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Col = namedtuple('Col', 'label, type')

def dataframe_check(*specification):
    def check_accepts(f):
        assert len(specification) <= f.__code__.co_argcount
        def new_f(*args, **kwds):
            for (df, specs) in zip(args, specification):
                spec_columns = [spec.label for spec in specs]
                assert (df.columns == spec_columns).all(), \
                  'Columns dont match specs {}'.format(spec_columns)

                spec_dtypes = [spec.type for spec in specs]
                assert (df.dtypes == spec_dtypes).all(), \
                  'Dtypes dont match specs {}'.format(spec_dtypes)
            return f(*args, **kwds)
        new_f.__name__ = f.__name__
        return new_f
    return check_accepts
```

I don't mind the complexity of the checking function but it adds a lot of boilerplate code.

```
@dataframe_check([Col('a', int), Col('b', int)],    #  df1
                 [Col('a', int), Col('b', float)],) #  df2
def f(df1, df2):
    return df1 + df2

f(df, df)
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of type-checking DataFrames? Something that looks more like [the new Python 3.6 static type-checking](https://medium.com/@ageitgey/learn-how-to-use-static-type-checking-in-python-3-6-in-10-minutes-12c86d72677b)?

Is it possible to implement it in mypy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps not the most pythonic way, but using a dict for your specs might do the trick (with keys as column names and values as [data types](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dtype.html?highlight=dtype#pandas.Series.dtype)):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['col1', 'col2'])
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype('int')
df['col2'] = df['col2'].astype('str')

cols_dtypes_req = {'col1':'int', 'col2':'object'} #'str' dtype is 'object' in pandas

def check_df(dataframe, specs):
    for colname in specs:
        if colname not in dataframe:
            return 'Column missing.'
        elif dataframe[colname].dtype != specs[colname]:
            return 'Data type incorrect.'
    for dfcol in dataframe:
        if dfcol not in specs:
            return 'Unexpected dataframe column.'
    return 'Dataframe meets specifications.'

print(check_df(df, cols_dtypes_req))
```

Comment: If you implement it with [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) you can also check the order of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

Try [pandera](https://github.com/pandera-dev/pandera)

> A data validation library for scientists, engineers, and analysts seeking correctness.