# Static typing/schema of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to hint about a pandas DataFrame's schema "statically" so that we can get code completion, static type checking, and just general predictability during coding?

I wouldn't mind duplicating the schema info in code and type annotation for this to work..

So maybe something roughly like mypy comment type annotations:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1.0, 2.4, 4.5], 'B': [1,2,3]})  # pd.schema: ('a': np.dtype(float)), ('B': np.dtype(int))
```

(or better yet have the schema specified in some external JSON file or such)

Then you can image things like `df.` auto-completing **during coding** to `df.a` or `df.B`. Or mypy (and any other static code analyzer) being able to infer the type of `df.B[0]` and such.

Although hopeful, I'm guessing this isn't really possible (or desired...). If so, what would be a good standard for writing good reusable code that returns `pd.DataFrame`'s with specific columns? So imagine there's a function `get_data() -> pd.DataFrame` that returns data with columns that are known in advance - how would you make this transparent to a user of this function? Anything smarter / more standardized than just spelling it out in the function's docstring?

Comment: SO you want to select the columns base on the datatype ?

Comment: No, I want to statically annotate the types of the columns

Comment: there seems to be some related wip in mypy: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/26792 also see some kind of workaround in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46412821/type-checking-pandas-dataframes

Comment: Related to this, is there a way to type a single Series that mypy will understand? Something like `pd.Series[str]`, `pd.Series[int]`, etc

Comment: [dataenforce](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce) wraps the DataFrame to allow exactly the kind of type hinting you describe.

Comment: [pylance](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/102) is also maybe looking to add this functionality

Answer (score 7):

[pandera](https://github.com/pandera-dev/pandera) should be what you need.

> A data validation library for scientists, engineers, and analysts seeking correctness.

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This may be something you already know, but a reliable way to get the auto-completion you are after is to develop code "live" in [Jupyter notebooks](https://jupyter.org/). It's very commonly used in data science applications - for your instance it might be appropriate to instantiate a version of the DataFrame with the types that you are looking for at the top of the notebook, then Jupyter will provide the autocomplete for the columns and types as you code. Obviously it has a big advantage over the IDE in terms of knowing what is in scope, because the dataframe is actually loaded into memory as you are developing.

Per above_c_level's comment, [dataenforce](https://github.com/CedricFR/dataenforce) looks promising for its connection with `pytest` (ie. testing after code is developed), but unless there are some fancy integrations with your IDE I don't think it will be able to match Jupyter's "live knowledge" of the object.

Comment: Not the direct answer to the question, but insightful nonetheless! Thanks @DaveB

Comment: That's true for scripting and prototyping but not for developing production level code.