# Get function arguments which are not default

Tags: python

I have this function:

```
def func(a, b, c=1, d=2):
    pass
```

With this:

```
import inspect
inspect.getargspec(func)
```

I get this result:

```
ArgSpec(args=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(1, 2))
```

Is there an easier way to find the arguments of a function which do not take default values?
With the statement above I have to do something ugly like this

```
ab = args[:-len(defaults)]
```

to retrieve those arguments. `ab` will now be `['a', 'b']`

Thanks.

**[EDIT]** For more clarifications:
I want to do this inspect outside the function `func`, not inside it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684434/best-way-to-check-function-arguments-in-python If you have a look around, people have asked this question many times.

Comment: This doesn't help me. It is not related to my question and, furthermore, I want to find this stuff outside the function `func`, not inside it.

Comment: @Maximas That link really doesn't mention default arguments at all...

Comment: I'm aware, however intuition and a little more research might make it work with default augments :)

Comment: Look at the implementation of `inspect.getargs`, if CPython devs could not come up with anything shorter then chances are that no, there is no easier way.

Comment: `inspect`, simplified, would look like this: `foo.func_code.co_varnames[:foo.func_code.co_argcount - len(foo.func_defaults)]`, but that would only work with simple functions, namely excluding Python2 tuple parameters like `def foo(x, (y, z), bar): pass`

Answer (score 1):

For Python 3.3 and newer using [Signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.Signature):

```
In [15]: [x for x, y in inspect.signature(func).parameters.items() if y.default is y.empty]
Out[15]: ['a', 'b']
```

Comment: Good point. Unfortunately, I'm using python 2.7 and there is no `signature` in `inspect`