# How to check whether function gets paramter or not

Tags: python-3.x, exception

I want to check  whether  user called function by passing any argument or not.

here is my function

```
def HEXtoRGB(hexlist):

    rgblist = []
    for i in range(len(hexlist)):
        h = hexlist[i].lstrip('#')
        rgb = tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
        rgblist.append(rgb)

    return(rgblist)


print(HEXtoRGB())
```

`HEXtoRGB()` takes `hexlist` as a paramter. if user called `HEXtoRGB()` function without argument then error message should print.
for that i tried error handling in python but its not working

```
def HEXtoRGB(hexlist):

    try:
        rgblist = []
        for i in range(len(hexlist)):
            h = hexlist[i].lstrip('#')
            rgb = tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
            rgblist.append(rgb)
    
        return(rgblist)
    except:
        print("Hex Color List Not Found")

print(HEXtoRGB())
```

above exception handling gives me same error

```
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(HEXtoRGB())
TypeError: HEXtoRGB() missing 1 required positional argument: 'hexlist'
```

**Is there any best way to handle missing argument error, In case user called function without argument**

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are trying to achieve? ``def HEXtoRGB(hexlist):`` already means that ``HEXtoRGB`` *must* be called with an argument, and it is an error to call ``HEXtoRGB()`` – as the ``TypeError`` shows. What other behaviour do you want?

Comment: want to handle type error, so that next time user can pass argument

Comment: It's the user making the error of calling ``HEXtoRGB`` wrongly, and *they* have to handle it. The user *can* already handle the error and pass an argument the next time. If ``HEXtoRGB`` internally handles the error, the user gets no immediate notification that they did something wrong and might limp on with an incorrect result. What behaviour do you expect to present to the user?

Comment: `def HEXtoRGB(hexlist==None):` and then test for `if not(hexlist)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to check function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684434/best-way-to-check-function-arguments)

Comment: Sometimes my fingers are a bit too swift. There is an extra `=` in my comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a default value for the parameter, e.g.:

```
def HEXtoRGB(hexlist=None):
    if hexlist is None:
        print("Hex Color List Not Found")
    else:
        rgblist = []
        for i in range(len(hexlist)):
            h = hexlist[i].lstrip('#')
            rgb = tuple(int(h[i:i+2], 16) for i in (0, 2, 4))
            rgblist.append(rgb)
        return(rgblist)

print(HEXtoRGB())
```

Note that `None` will be the return value in this case. You might want to return something else.