Macro like code to use inside Python functions
Is there a way to define macro-like code to use inside many functions which handle the same data (arguments of the same nature with the same name)? I have many function like "f" below (almost the same interface, they do different things, on the same kind of data). And I have to repeat the same argument validation code for each one.
def f(arg1, arg2, ...):
    # validation code
        # it checks and eventually change arg1, arg2, etc.
    # function code


Is there a way to define a "validation_macro" and then do something like this?
def f(arg1, arg2, ...):
    # expand validation_macro
    # function code



Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684434/best-way-to-check-function-arguments - this is not exactly the same question, but a few of the answers there would answer this question, too.

If your macro raises an ecxeption, a simpler soloution is to define a validation method.
def is_valid(arg1, arg2, ...):
    if not valid:
        raise ValueError()


def f(arg1,arg2,...):
    is_valid(arg1, arg2, ...)
    # function Code

This will also work if you want to correct values. But my lazyness says, that decorators are the better option for this.
def correct_params(arg1, arg2, ...):
    # correct values
    return arg1, arg2, ...

def f(arg1, arg2, ...):
    arg1, arg2, ... = correct_params(arg1, arg2, ...)
# function code 

Addendum
There was a good answer to demonstrate decoraters. Because this answer is deleted, I will add an example.
A decorator is a function that accepts as first parameter a function and returns a function that calls the given function.
Just for completeness a decorator can also accept a class or method and return a class or method, but that is out of topic for this question.
For example a validation decorator can look like this.
It accepts as parameter a function and creates a function runs the validation "macro" and then calls the given function.
The decorator then returns this "validation-macro-function".
from functools import wraps


def validation(function):
    @wraps(function)
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        # validation code here
        return function(arg1, arg2)

    return wrapper

The use of @wraps is not necessary, but I highly recommend it. Reflection is not working as expected without it.
Now you can use it like this.
def f1(arg1, arg2):
    pass

f1(1,2)  # function call without validation

f1 = validation(f1)

f1(1,2)  # function call with validation

And there is also some syntactic sugar for this. The code above can also be written like this:
@validation
def f(arg1, arg2):
    pass

f(1,2)  # function call with validation

